# WebClient DownloadFile return error 500, but file exist

Tags: c#, webclient

I working on a webservice that download files. On input I've got a list of files, with their url. When I put the url on my browser, I can download the file.

So I manage my service to download all the file on a specific path. This work like a charm, but sometimes, the server return 'error 500'

> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
>      at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(Uri address)

or

> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
>      at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)

. I don't have access to this server, so I can't modify the code.

Here is my code

```
public static string DownloadFile(string url, string path)
    {
        string fileName = null;

        int nbTry = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < nbTry; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                //Use WebDownload class and set timet for 10 seconds
                using (WebDownload client = new WebDownload(10000))
                {
                    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)");
                    //Englobe with try catch in order to manage Error 500 when looping on download method

                    client.OpenRead(url);

                    string header_contentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
                    string filename = new ContentDisposition(header_contentDisposition).FileName;

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    //Start the download and copy the file to the destinationFolder
                    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), path + @"\" + filename);
                    //If it's good, stop the loop
                    i = nbTry;
                    fileName = filename;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ILog logError = LogManager.GetLogger("error");
                logError.Error("Error in DownloadFile", e);
                logError.Error("Url : " + url + " Path : " + path);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

In order to manage timeout on WebClient, I've created the WebDownload class

```
public class WebDownload : WebClient
{
    public int TimeOut { get; set; }

    public WebDownload() : this(60000) { }

    public WebDownload(int timeout)
    {
        this.TimeOut = timeout;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if(request != null)
        {
            request.Timeout = this.TimeOut;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

My problem is to manage this error 500 and try again to download the file in short time. I actually get stuck for 200s when it fails. I can have 100 files, so I can't waste 20 000s for download this files.

Any advice, help, idea is welcome.

Comment: fileName = filename? You hate the people you work with, don't you?

Comment: Also, 500 doesn't mean file doesn't exist. That's the job of 404. 500 means there was an error in the request. It can be any other error too.

Comment: The return error is System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out